# Adding mysqli_connect() function stops running the script

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

When I add the `mysqli_connect` statement in my php file it stops working the whole script. If make this statement comment my php file works as expected. I am adding this file to a wordpress website.

I have tried to connect using mysql_connect() also but the result is same.

**My Code:**

```
<?php

require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php');

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//phpinfo();

echo DB_NAME ."<br>";
echo DB_USER ."<br>";
echo DB_PASSWORD ."<br>";
echo DB_HOST."<br>"


$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
// database port is also 3306 which is default

if (!$conn) {
    echo  "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

`php.info()` outputs that mysqli is installed is also enabled.

Do I need to include some file to access `mysqli_connect()` function.

How can I connect to the database?

Comment: Can you write whats error you are getting..?

Comment: You missed semi colon at echo DB_HOST."<br>"

Comment: @SaadSuri but the `echo` statements are fine and shows the proper output if I remove the `mysqli_connect()` and oter db related statements but in combinations I get nothing in output

Comment: Because you don't need to terminate the last line of code. It can be done through ?>. When you remove your all db related statements so echo DB_HOST."<br>" becomes the last statement which will be successfully terminated by ?>

Comment: @SaadSuri yes it worked for me.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I'm posting this an answer so you can close this question @stackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a semicolon at **echo DB_HOST."**

```
    require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php');

    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //phpinfo();

    echo DB_NAME ."<br>";
    echo DB_USER ."<br>";
    echo DB_PASSWORD ."<br>";
    echo DB_HOST."<br>";


    $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    // database port is also 3306 which is default

    if (!$conn) {
        echo  "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. You missed semi colon at end of `DB_HOST."<br>"` line. Every thing is fine in code.

```
<?php

require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php');

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//phpinfo();

echo DB_NAME ."<br>";
echo DB_USER ."<br>";
echo DB_PASSWORD ."<br>";
echo DB_HOST."<br>";


$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
// database port is also 3306 which is default

if (!$conn) {
    echo  "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```